# RenderingTemplates for EditProfile.aspx - Which RenderTemplate uses the MySite?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, moss

I am working on Replacing Default text editor in MOSS. So I found good [blog](http://www.notesfor.net/post/Enhance-SharePoint-rich-text-field.aspx) for change in regular sites, but not in MySites collections.

Looking for RenderingTemplate for Richtextbox(ProfileEditor) in EditProfile.aspx page. `EditProfile.aspx` has ProfileEditorXXXX. I know DefaultTemplates.ascx will render templates for regular sites collections `(<SharePoint:RenderingTemplate ID="RichTextField" runat="server">)`.

So now I need to know Which RenderTemplate uses the MySite. I have to replace `Richtext` in the MySites.